# Определить размеры l-системы

Tags: алгоритм

На всякий случай: [L-системы](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system)

В простом виде, в аксиому подставляется формула N раз, где N равно числу итераций. 
Получается длинная лента, по которой далее происходит построение.
Проблема в том, что размер конечного "фрактала" может меняться довольно в серьезных пределах. Я вижу только один способ уместить результат в область просмотра: построить дважды. Первый раз - узнать максимальные границы, второй - уже строить с поправкой по длине.

Есть ли более умный способ?

**UPD:**

Пример работы:
Угол π/3
Аксиома F
Подстановка F-F++F-F
Это кривая Коха.

Итерации

1. F-F++F-F длина 3F (так как -F++F из-за поворота дают лишь половину своей длины)
2. F-F++F-F - F-F++F-F ++ F-F++F-F - F-F++F-F длина 9F
3. длина 27F ну и так далее

Тут все легко. Но есть формулы с ветвлением или с многоуровневыми подстановками через другие переменные. Вот там уже сложнее.

Comment: меня устроит даже ответ "есть/нет". :)

Comment: Хм, а почему бы не построить результат полностью, подсчитать bounding box, а затем _при выводе_ подсчитанного результата привести координаты к нужному интервалу? Таким образом, мы считаем лишь один раз.

Или запоминать все вычисленные точки дороже, чем пересчитать ещё раз? Если так, то и правда лучшего пути чем двойной пересчёт не видно.

Comment: @VladD, потому что оно строится по мере движения по ленте. Или рекурсивно(тогда вообще швах). Хранить координаты много затратнее, чем ленту: в ленте палка - это одна буква, иногда буква и несколько плюсов. Координаты - минимум (1:2)(3:4) 10 байт, а если с плавающей точкой - все 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Немножко формул](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alfonso_De_La_Puente/publication/220499153_Determination_of_fractal_dimensions_from_equivalent_L_systems/links/0c96051a74f82aeb90000000) - типа "есть".

Comment: Еще не читал, там регаться надо. Вечером зарегаюсь.

Comment: черт. с гугля сразу pdf открывался. отсюда страница. в общем региться не надо, надо "no, thanks" нажать и справа view и сразу download.